# reactjs: how to load data dynamically based on data just a loaded before

Tags: reactjs

In my reactjs page i will be obtaining a list of ids and imgs from api using axios and store it in the state.

Example:

```
[
{id: 21321321,img_url: },
{id: 97777798},img_url: }
....
]
```

Once i get the data  using axios i will be displaying the list of images.

Meanwhile i want to get further data based on the id using axios. I will have 4 ids in a list at a time. So again i have to make 4 requests and get the corresponding data and display them below the images.

If i store the data in the state like below

```
[
{id: 21321321,img_url: ,further_data: ... },
{id: 97777798,img_url: ,further_data: ...},
....
]
```

i will be refreshing the DOM 4 times. Because in reactjs whenever we change the state it refreshes the DOM.

Also How to trigger in the div when the dom of each item is loaded then start collecting extra data

Comment: 250 requests is a lot, but you could make a request per object in the array and wait for all of them to finish with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) before you finally put all the data in state just once.

Comment: sorry assuming i have only 4

Comment: i want fisrt the 4 imgs to be displayed, then add the extracted data below. it need not be in sequence. just like how images load

Comment: You can get images in componentwillmount and set state and then get image details in componentdidmount.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid refreshing the dom in this case? Updating the page as new assets are fetched is how web pages have always worked. Waiting for everything can lead to very slow performance or dead locks.

Comment: ok i will try to update

Answer (score 0):

You could always Send an array of ID handle it on the backend & return an array of objects.

Instead of sending 4 individual request send one that gets all 4.